# Collect controls in a form c#

Tags: c#

I have a form in which there are some buttons. I'd like put their references in an array.Is it possible with a foreach ?

I want to do this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button[] all = new Button[5];
        all[0] = button1;
        all[1] = button2;
        all[3] = button3;
        all[4] = button4;
    }
```

I've already tried

```
int i=0;
foreach (Button p in Form1)
{
    all[i]= p;
    i++;
}
```

But I can't use a foreach on a Form.
The same thing if the buttons are in a panel.

What can I do to collect all buttons quickly?
Thanks :)

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? WPF? SilverLight?

Comment: The simplest way would probably be `Form1.Controls.OfType<Button>()`. If you *really* need it as an array, you can tack on `.ToArray()`.

Comment: You would have to iterate the this.Controls collection.  And keep your fingers crossed that they are in the order you want them.  Clearly there is nothing wrong with doing it explicitly.  Use the initializer syntax to make it more condense.  And declare the variable correctly, it is pretty useless as a local variable of your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `Controls` collection of your form or container, which contains every control directly in it.

Beware that this will also include non-Buttons; call `.OfType<Button>()` to filter.

So instead of the foreach you can initialize an array like this:

```
Button[] all = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks :) lucky doesn't matter the order in the array :)

Answer (score 1):

Every `Control` has a `Controls` property which is a `ControlCollection`. You can get all `Button`s on a `Control` (as a `Form` or a `Panel`) like this:

```
foreach(var button in control.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{ ... }
```

But this will only give you the `Button`s that are contained directly by this `control`. If you want to get **all `Button`s** in your `Form` on *all* `Panel`s, `GroupBox`s etc, you need to recurse through the `Controls`like in this example:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    // ...

    private static IEnumerable<Button> GetAllButtons(Control control)
    {
        return control.Controls.OfType<Button>().Concat(control.Controls.OfType<Control>().SelectMany(GetAllButtons));
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithAllButtons()
    {
        foreach(var button in GetAllButtons(this))
        { // do something with button }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) lucky doesn't matter the order in the array :)